# What is the intended meaning of this sentence? 「これはまさに自虐ネタであるそうだ。」 w

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension

<sub>(  I first learned about this Jp article (and "diving" incident) from [What does 「中」 mean in 「そう危険なものではなかった中、彼の姿は。。。」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38799/what-does-%e4%b8%ad-mean-in-%e3%81%9d%e3%81%86%e5%8d%b1%e9%99%ba%e3%81%aa%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e4%b8%ad-%e5%bd%bc%e3%81%ae%e5%a7%bf%e3%81%af) )</sub>

The following excerpt comes from this news article: http://news.livedoor.com/article/detail/11944976/

> ビルからビルへダイナミックに飛び移る、そんなCGアクションシーンに強く憧れていたのであろうグラントさん。ピッツバーグ郊外のインディアナ・タウンシップの出身で大学ではコミュニケーション学と映画学を専攻していたそうだ。しかもグラントさんはこのニュースを報じた『ピッツバーグ・ポスト・ガゼット』紙・編集局次長の息子とのこと。これはまさに自虐ネタであるそうだ。

1. What is the intended meaning of this last sentence? これはまさに自虐ネタであるそうだ。
2. How would you write that intended meaning (or something like it) in good Jp prose?

Also, please list other errors or awkward passages (in the article).

```
      ... 専攻していたそうだ。 <---  これも変だろ w
```

Comment: What's wrong about  「専攻していたそうだ」?

Comment: You can leave the deleted answer and edit it until it is a full answer and then undelete it. Else, you can add it to your question.

Comment: Please remove this comment below [ Can you not edit your original post? ] because its meaning is unclear. I wondered if this was a form of harassment. I also wondered if this referred to my adding the link to the top of the Original Post (the original question).  I wondered if this was a way of insultingly chastising me for something I have done (and if so, is it something I can undo?).   It turns out that it was a short insulting comment chastising me for something I planned to do. Please remove the short, insulting comment. Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with 「専攻して い た そうだ」 is that it may sound like it's no longer true.   The incident happened only 5 days (?) before the Jp article.  ____________ In a Jp newspaper article, it's easy to avoid saying something like [who was majoring in ... (at least) at the time of the accident]  --- see my example in my (now invisible?) answer. ---- ビルからビルへとダイナミックに飛び移る、そんなCGアクションシーンに憧れていたのか。 ピッツバーグ郊外のインディアナ・タウンシップの出身で大学ではコミュニケーション学と映画学専攻のグラントさん、驚いたことには  ......................  _______________> しかも <---   これも変だろ w

Comment: @H.Ha I don't think anyone intended to harass or insult.  I think the commenter was genuinely confused as to why you were posting an answer rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. これはまさに自虐ネタであるそうだ。

「自虐ネタ」is something like an embarrassing story that you might tell to jokingly put yourself down.

I haven't read the whole article, but from this excerpt it sounds like グラントさん should be pretty embarrassed by not knowing about some news because of his background in Movie CG and his father working at the newspaper that had the story in it.

So you might translate the last sentence as something like, "You can imagine what an embarrassing situation this would be for him."

> 2. I'm not sure what you're asking, but maybe something like this?

「グラントさんにとってはきっと恥ずかしいことでしょう」

Comment: `グラントさんにとってはきっと恥ずかしい`-> グラントさんのお父さん（= 編集局次長) の自虐ネタだろう、ってことです。恥ずかしいのはきっとグラントさんのお父さんです。息子の恥を自ら新聞に載せているわけです。